Celery returns wrong info about current tasks in one worker
I have a bundle which contains Celery and RabbitMQ for tasks and FastApi app for web requests.
The celery app starts from command prompt with celery -A celery_app worker -l info -P gevent.
Rabbit is deployed in Docker Container.
FastApi starts from python script.
Here is the code. The question is below.
fastapi_app/main.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from fastapi import FastAPI
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from celery_app.tasks import task, get_current_tasks
from celery_app.celery import c_app
from fastapi_app.model import Worker, Task

f_app = FastAPI()


@f_app.post("/task/")
def run_task():
    _task = task.apply_async()
    return {"task_id": _task.id}


@f_app.get("/task_info/{task_id}")
def get_progress(task_id):
    result = AsyncResult(task_id, app=c_app)
    return Task(id=task_id, state=result.state, meta=result.info)


@f_app.get("/curr_progress/")
def get_current_progress():
    response = {'workers': []}
    for worker, tasks_list in get_current_tasks().items():
        worker_tasks_id = [task_.get('id') for task_ in tasks_list]
        worker_ = Worker(name=worker)
        for id_ in worker_tasks_id:
            result = AsyncResult(id_, app=c_app)
            worker_.tasks.append(Task(id=id_, state=result.state, meta=result.info))
        response['workers'].append(worker_)
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(f_app, host="localhost", port=8000)


fastapi_app/model.py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Any, Optional


class Task(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str] = None
    state: Optional[str] = None
    meta: dict | Any | None = None


class Worker(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    tasks: List[Task] = list()

celery_app/tasks.py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import threading
import time
from celery_app.celery import c_app


def get_current_tasks() -> dict:
    i = c_app.control.inspect()
    return i.active()


def get_registered_tasks() -> dict:
    i = c_app.control.inspect()
    return i.registered()


@c_app.task(bind=True)
def task(self):
    print(f'task started in {threading.current_thread()}. Thread alive:')
    for i in threading.enumerate():
        print(i)

    n = 60
    for i in range(0, n):
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'done': i, 'total': n})
        time.sleep(1)
    print(f'task finished in {threading.current_thread()}\n')
    return n

celery_app/celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

c_app = Celery('celery_app',
               broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost',
               backend='rpc://',
               include=['celery_app.tasks'])


There, in fastapi_app/main.py I have the function, which starts the task run_task() and the function, which get the current progress of all running tasks get_current_progress().
The last one depends on celery.result.AsyncResult() which depends on update_state() method in task(self) function in celery_app/tasks.py.
Here is the problem. When I start only one task by requesting FastApi server, task's progress displays correctly.
{
  "workers": [
    {
      "name": "celery@wsmsk1n3075",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "271531c2-48e6-4c71-a9ef-31bce434c649",
          "state": "PROGRESS",
          "meta": {
            "done": 3,
            "total": 60
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

But when I start multiple tasks (send a couple of task-requests to FastApi server) displaying becomes incorrect. Especially the progress's meta info.
{
  "workers": [
    {
      "name": "celery@wsmsk1n3075",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "4d05d0f0-f058-4372-8eec-c84853188655",
          "state": "PROGRESS",
          "meta": {
            "done": 9,
            "total": 60
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "0ca82db4-7e04-4bfd-9d73-6a190decd4c6",
          "state": "PROGRESS",
          "meta": null
        },
        {
          "id": "ba8aa34b-e185-47cf-bed3-f3ca07257afc",
          "state": "PROGRESS",
          "meta": null
        },
        {
          "id": "3e2941f5-1285-4062-aea0-31a3c9b1cc21",
          "state": "PROGRESS",
          "meta": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

It's important to note, that in celery all 4 tasks are being executed in separate threads:
[2024-07-23 13:02:06,427: WARNING/MainProcess] <_DummyThread(Dummy-6, started daemon 1901360139936)>
[2024-07-23 13:02:06,427: WARNING/MainProcess] <_DummyThread(Dummy-7, started daemon 1901360142016)>
[2024-07-23 13:02:06,428: WARNING/MainProcess] <_DummyThread(Dummy-8, started daemon 1901360137056)>
[2024-07-23 13:02:06,429: WARNING/MainProcess] <_DummyThread(Dummy-9, started daemon 1901360139776)>

So, they must have their own progress (which seems not to be like that as you can see in the last json block).
How can I obtain every task state in multiple-task case, like it was in the solo-task example?
UDP: Looks like it's a timing problem somewhere under the celery hood. If we add some sleep() before every AsyncResult like that:
@f_app.get("/curr_progress/")
def get_current_progress():
    response = {'workers': []}
    for worker, tasks_list in get_current_tasks().items():
        worker_tasks_id = [task_.get('id') for task_ in tasks_list]
        worker_ = Worker(name=worker)
        for id_ in worker_tasks_id:
            time.sleep(1)
            result = AsyncResult(id_, app=c_app)
            worker_.tasks.append(Task(id=id_, state=result.state, meta=result.info))
        response['workers'].append(worker_)
    return response

we will have 1 sec shift for every AsyncResult but, at least we will have the actual progress of the tasks with their meta (with 1 sec outdating shift for every previous result in the result ofc).
The same behaviour is achieved when we try to get progress for current task by it's task_id manualy, in fastapi_app/main.py get_progress(task_id) function. Just time.sleep is going to be replaced with human timing.

After some research I figured out that tasks results, which stored in RPC backend, are only available in the original Celery application instance and can't be reached from another application.
After that knowledge I still don't really know how it "worked" somehow in my example before, but, changing RPC backend to permanent storage, like Postgres solves the problem at all.
I've moved all configuration to the separate file, so, here is the backend configuration:
result_backend = 'db+postgresql://admin:root@localhost/celery_test_db'
result_extended = True

The last setting is necessary if you want to see all task's info in database, like args, kwargs, queue, worker etc.
